# How to append 2 headers to post in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular

How to append 2 headers in that code:

```
 postData(json: PortfolioVO) {
      var njson = JSON.stringify(json);

      var  headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type' , 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    headers.append('Accept' , 'application/json');


    return this.http.post('http://www.develop.nivafex.com/rest/portfolios/en', njson,
      { headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());

  }
```

This code doesn't work.

Comment: Any advance on *"doesn't work"*? Also, your whitespace seems inconsistent; this is unlikely to cause errors in itself, but indicates a lack of care that might cause some elsewhere.

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose the problem. "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you're looking for:

```
postData(json: PortfolioVO) {
      var njson = JSON.stringify(json);

      var  headers = new Headers({
          'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      });    

     return this.http
                .post('http://www.develop.nivafex.com/rest/portfolios/en', 
                      njson,
                      { headers: headers })
                .map(res => res.json());    
  }
```